# Как открыть .py файл или .exe через python?

Tags: python

Как открыть .py файл или .exe через python? Тоесть в редакторе кода в файле python открыть другой .py файл, код показан ниже

```
def callback(sender, app_data, user_data):
    f = open('test.py')
```

Comment: какой другой файл? test.py? что вообще понимается под открыть в данном случае? exe файл нельзя открыть

Comment: Вам нужно открыть файл в ide или запустить его?

Comment: запустить его надо

Answer (score 0):

Для запуска файла можете использовать встроенный в Python модуль `os`. И его метод `system`.

Вот код:

```py
import os

os.system(r"ПУТЬ К ВАШЕМУ ФАЙЛУ")
```

Второй вариант использовать `subprocess` - также встроенный в Python модуль.

Пример кода:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(r"ПУТЬ К ВАШЕМУ ФАЙЛУ")
```